# Does Radiant support Rails 3 now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, radiant

I use `gem install radiant` to install radiant, and I found that it doesn't support Rails 3. But, I found there is a file named "GemfileRails3" in the source code of Radiant on Github, I wonder why is that. Does Radiant really not support Rails3?

Answer (score 0):

Radiant still does not support Rails 3 at this moment. A lot of work towards that has been done, but the project is lacking momentum, making it hard to say when this can be released.

Comment: You're welcome.. could you mark your question as answered? Thanks!